# What metric should be minimized when searching from a subset of points that are as uniformly distributed across the space as possible?

Tags: optimization, uniform-distribution, evolutionary-algorithms

Given a set of *n* points, I have to find a subset of given size *m<n*, so that the *m* points are as uniformly distributed as possible across the volume enclosed by the convex hull of set *n*. See example figure:

[image]

Here we have a toy 2D example of the problem with *n=600* and *m=100*. I am solving this problem using Evolutionary Algorithm and I do not know what the fitness (objective function) to minimize should be. I tried minimizing electrostatic potential $$E=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j\frac{1}{|r_i-r_j|}$$ following the idea of the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem), however the resulting output is clearly incorrect (see figure below, red points denote solution found by the evolutionary algorithm) as the density of the selected points is higher at the edges. I tried squaring values in denominator of given equation for E, but the solutions are still clearly suboptimal.

What is the objective function I should minimize to get what I want? Note that I want to solve this problem in **high dimension space for arbitrary set of points** with unknown distribution.

[image]

Comment: You are saying nothing about the density among the m "uniform" points. Say, m=4. Shall the square (uniform lattice of 4 points) be small or big, and how much.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The answer is not completely clear to me. The points should be uniform in the space enclosed by the n points. I want the points to be (0.25, 0.25), (0.75, 0.25), (0.25, 0.75), and (0.75, 0.75), although I assume the entropy is higher if they are in the corners (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1).

Comment: There exist statistics which are used to check if the data are more clustered than uniformly random or more regular than uniformly random. One of them is Hopkins statistic of cluster tendency. Read about it. But it tests the existing data and I don't know how it can be utilized to _select_ a subset of data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment by @ttnphns, Hopkin's statistic answered my question. In the genetic algorithm optimization process, minimazing the Hopkin's statistic would converge to finding the solutions with more uniform distribution.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, 
probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our 
standards. Can you expand on it? We can also turn it into 
a comment.